# Bootstrap 4 columns going under each other

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="description">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#4faf54">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-R4pqcOYV8lt7snxMQO/HSbVCFRPMdrhAFMH+vr9giYI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
   <span class="navbar-brand">Title</span>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
     <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
     <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
     <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
     <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

No matter what I do, I can't get the columns to stay next to each other, they will always go one under the other.

I literally tried copy pasting the grid system example from the documentation and that doesn't work either.

I'm using the latest version of Firefox for Mac.

Comment: You have some CSS in there that we have no idea what does. My guess is that it has something to do with that :)

Comment: you are using bootstrap version 3.4 and using column class of newer version try using class col-md-2 or use latest version of bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code it is clear that you are using version 3 of Bootstrap but the grid system that you are using is for Bootstrap 4, basically BS 3 doesn't have any class like `col-2` try using `col-sm-2` in place of that or change the version of Bootstrap resources to Version 4 which uses css flexbox instead of floats.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are using Bootstrap 3.4.1 and col-x class is not supported in this version.

Try to upgrade your Bootstrap version to 4:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="description">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#4faf54">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
            <span class="navbar-brand">Title</span>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <h1>TEST</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <h1>TEST</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <h1>TEST</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <h1>TEST</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="description">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#4faf54">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <span class="navbar-brand">Title</span>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <h1>TEST</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <h1>TEST</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <h1>TEST</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <h1>TEST</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-R4pqcOYV8lt7snxMQO/HSbVCFRPMdrhAFMH+vr9giYI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: use bootstrap 4 instead of bootstrap 3,

Answer (score 0):

the grid system worked for me on boostrap version 3.4.1, just need to add the grid class which makes it responsive:

- xs (for phones - screens less than 768px wide)
- sm (for tablets - screens equal to or greater than 768px wide)
- md (for small laptops - screens equal to or greater than 992px wide)
- lg (for laptops and desktops - screens equal to or greater than 1200px wide)

for example with the class "col-sm-2" on a screen larger than 768px they will float next to each other

Comment: yep, just confirmed from the horse's mouth, so to speak that the grid system just exist in version 3.4:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid